# Does Bonded add to Fireteam damage?

Tags: damage, planet-mercenary

Normally, Bonded offers the following:

> Your team only takes orders from you. Also, it gains +1 Combat, +1 Mental,
>   +1 Physical, and +1 Social (regardless of its member composition)

Does that include damage (adding a 1d6)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not provide a damage boost.

Source: I wrote the game.

Comment: Thank you, Alan. I suspected that was the case, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: I'm happy to see Planet Mercenary get a question ^_^ I have my copy but don't expect to ever play it. T_T

Comment: @gatherer818: We have a game running on Discord/Roll20 right now, recruited from the Reddit forum, so it can happen. Honestly, the biggest barrier to someone running a game is that they have to manually import all of the cards.